# How to group by distinct values in one column in r so I can generate a density plot?

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this

```
CAB_TYPE   Price
Uber       10
Uber       5
Lyft       6
Uber       7
Lyft       8
Uber       7
```

And I want to group it to two datasets like this

```
Uber      10
Uber      5
Uber      7
Uber      7
```

and

```
Lyft     6
Lyft     8
```

So I can generate a density plot of the price. I tried to look it up but I'm not sure how to describe this problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just do `df1 %>% arrange(CAB_TYPE)`

Comment: To divide into two datasets you can do `split(df, df$CAB_TYPE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you are trying to make a density plot of the price of either Uber or Lyft. Am I right ?

If your data are organized like this example:

```r
df = data.frame(Cab_type = c("Uber","Uber","Lyft","Uber","Lyft","Uber"),
                Price = c(10,5,6,7,8,7))

> df
  Cab_type Price
1     Uber    10
2     Uber     5
3     Lyft     6
4     Uber     7
5     Lyft     8
6     Uber     7
```

You don't need to do anything except plotting them using `ggplot2` and passing the `color` argument in the `aes`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Price, fill = Cab_type)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green","orange"))
```

[image]

NB: 
1) If you want to fill the area under the curve, use `fill` argument in the `aes`.

2) If you want to change color, add the `scale_fill_manual` function

3) If you want to add some transparency, you can use `alpha = ..` in `geom_density` function. 
Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you! Another question, how can I change the color of the lines? And I want to fill the area under the curve with transparent colors. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It's so much clearer than the r documentation...